# How to write lambda function for Rotation of RDS password using secrets manager?

Tags: python, aws-lambda, aws-secrets-manager

I need help writing the lambda function:
I have two users one readonly and one read_write_user. I want to rotate the password of read_write_user periodically with the help of readonly user. Periodically means , I will set a cron expression for a lambda to run every 15 days something like that. I do not want to use rotation configuration of secrets manager.
How can I achieve this?
I tried using https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-secrets-manager-rotation-lambdas/blob/master/SecretsManagerRDSMySQLRotationMultiUser/lambda_function.py but it is way complex than what I need.

Comment: I'm confused. Your title says you want to use Secrets Manager, but your question says you do not want to use it. Could you please edit your question to clarify your desire? Do you wish to keep the current password in Secrets Manager? Also, what do you mean by "with the help of readonly user"?

Comment: I want to use secrets manager to retrieve the secrets storied but I do not want to use the rotation configuration option that secret manager provides.

Comment: In that case, you'll have to write your own code (or extract relevant code from that function) that logs into the database and sets the password. See the part that mentions `IDENTIFIED BY`, which sets the password.

Comment: can you please help me how to extract and make the code work?

Answer (score 0):

If this is a standard RDS database, you can use the Secrets Manager console to set this up for you and you will not need to create your own lambda.

Put your master RDS password in secrets manager. If you do not remember the master password, you can [reset it using the RDS console](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/reset-master-user-password-rds/). Now you can rotate both your read-only and read-write users by [setting this up in the console](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/secretsmanager/latest/userguide/rotating-secrets-rds.html). When you go to set it up, chose the option "Use a secret that I have previously stored in AWS Secrets Manager" and select your master password as the password to use to perform the rotation.

You can also setup ["single user rotation"](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/secretsmanager/latest/userguide/rotating-secrets-one-user-one-password.html) on your master password. When you set it up in the console, just choose "Use the same credentials" when it asks what credentials to use.